# user sudo permissions but not switch to root user

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, administrator

Please help, if I grant permissions to a user in the `/etc/sudoers.d` file like so:

```
newuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

That user has all permissions. But I don´t want this user to be able to switch to the root user. Is this possible?

Or can anyone tell me how can I set up this user to be able to perform the most common admin tasks but not all of them like he is root.

Comment: It is self-contradictory. `newuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` means in English that the user `newuser` is allowed to run any command as any user / group  on any computer where this policy applies. That includes running a shell as root...

Answer (score 2):

Read `man sudoers`. Once you manage to decode the Extended Backus-Naur Form (see [Extended Backus-Naur form article on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)), you'll see that `ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` is the least restrictive way of using `sudo`.

You can restrict `newuser` in many ways.

Comment: The link you gave is broken. I am also interested in it, please could you fix it.

Comment: Th link to Wikipedia works for me. Not broken.